How to access the array which is returned from macro function in velocity templates?
When the below script is executed, the array variable data received from the test macro function is properly stored, but when $var.size or $var.get(0) is executed, it does not work.

Since $var works properly, I think the array object was successfully delivered through the macro function. However, I don't know why $var.size doesn't work.
What needs to be modified to make it work properly?
#macro (test)
#set ($variable = ["a", "b","c"])
#macro (test)
    #set ($variable = ["a", "b","c"])
$variable##
#end

#macro (test2)
    #set ($var = "#test()")
    $var<br>
    $var.size()<br>
    $var.get(0)<br>
#end

#test2()


=== current result ===
[a, b, c]
$var.size()
$var.get(0)

The expected operational results are as follows.
[a, b, c]
3
a
